# WPF GroupStyle error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, grouping

I have a `GroupStyle` in a `DataGrid` as shown below:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CompassLogDataGrid"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Compasscollection}, IsAsync=True,                 Mode=OneTime}"
    Height="auto"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Log4NetDataGridStyle}">

      <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
          <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}" />
      </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
      ...
</DataGrid>
```

and the `GroupStyle`:

```
    <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">

    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="False" />

    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="0,0,0,5" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Expander IsExpanded="False"
                          Background="#FF112255"
                          BorderBrush="#FF002255"
                          Foreground="Black"
                          BorderThickness="1,1,1,5">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                       Foreground="White"
                                       Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                       Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                       Width="100" />
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                       Foreground="White"
                                       Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Expander.Header>

                    <Expander.Content>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Expander.Content>
                </Expander>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

this code produce the following `Error`:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=AreRowDetailsFrozen; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridDetailsPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectiveScrollingOrientation' (type 'SelectiveScrollingOrientation')
>       System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HeadersVisibility; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridRowHeader' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

How can I fix This?

Comment: I don't think it's a grouping or style issue. I've just tired your style and it works fine on my `DataGrid`.